# Looping a request that returns results in order they were put in

Tags: json, node.js, httprequest

This code is the same structure as my code:

```
for (var i in UserNameArray)
        {
 var Urls = "https://some online api"+UserNameArray[i]+"api key";
 //the url changes by plugging in the next array value every iteration.
            request({
                url: Urls,
                json: true
            }, function (error, response, body) {

                if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                    console.log(body); 
                }
            })
        }
```

It returns a json from the URL correctly, but it's printing it out by which every iterated request returns first. How can I change my code so that it prints out the requests in the order that they were requested? This is important as I will have to traverse the specific JSON with a specific value from UserNameArray.

Comment: What exactly you want to do after getting  body except console?

Comment: I know that you can achieve it with this library http://caolan.github.io/async/

Comment: Another array named IdResultArray is declared above the for loop, then I will say IdResultArray [i] = body[UserNameArray[i]].id. I will then update my database with it and I will output it to a webpage using express and EJS.

Comment: Actually this is a function in my async.waterfall, which part of the async module will assist me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

Im going trough all of them, and storing the response in an result array (by index). Then when all of them have finished it goes to a final callback where we print them (in order) to the console.

```
var async =  require('async'); 
var result = [];

async.eachOf(UserNameArray, function(name, i, cb) {

    //the url changes by plugging in the next array value every iteration.
   var Urls = "https://some online api"+UserNameArray[i]+"api key";
  request({
    url: Urls,
    json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {

    // checking if something went wrong..    
    if (error) return cb(error);

    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        // storing the response to our result array
        result[i] = body;
        // do a callback, telling that we are done here
        cb();
    }

  })

}, function(err) {

        // all done.

        // lets print the errors if something went wrong
        if (err) console.error(err.message);

        // lets print our results
        for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
        console.log(result[i]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this before that install async using npm

```
var async =  require('async'); 
async.forEach(UserNameArray, function (i, cb) {

        var Urls = "https://some online api"+i+"apikey";
        request({
            url: Urls,
            json: true
        }, function (error, response, body) {

            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                console.log(body); 

            }
           cb();
        })

      });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I implemented your response, unfortunately it's still returning the results not in the order they were put in. I put it in a function in my waterfall, it also runs after all functions in the waterfall are done.